# Project as dependency not packaged in .war file

Tags: java, maven, jersey, war

I have a Jersey Tomcat project B that depends on another similar project A, I am developing on Eclipse.

When I run A on it's own, it runs with no problems. The export configuration for its build path is:

[image]

And the deployment assembly for A is:

[image]

Then, for project B, I imported project A into the java build path like this:

[image]

The build path for project B looks like this:

[image]

And the web deployment assembly for project B is:

[image]

Project A is listed as a .war, I am not sure if this is related to the issue. The pom.xml for project A lists war as packaging:

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

The pom.xml for project B mentions project A like so:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>some.project.A</groupId>
        <artifactId>flocktracker</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Eclipse doesn't show any issues until when I try to deploy in a Tomcat server, whe I get this error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: some/project/A/SomeClassInA
    at some.project.B.SomeClassInB.<init>(SomeClassInB.java:##)
```

If it helps, SomeClassInA is an implementation of `org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig`.

SomeClassInA is mentioned in the web.xml file like so:

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
    <param-value>some.projectA.SomeClassInA</param-value>
</init-param>
```

SomeClassInA is an implementation of `javax.ws.rs.ext.ContextResolver<T>`

I used right click on `project > export > WAR file` to examine the contents of the file and I couldn't find the classes of Project A on WEB-INF/classess or elsewhere in the .war file.

Is there something I am missing or that I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't mix Eclipse and Maven mechanisms.

Answer (score 1):

Keeping the Eclipse tooling aside, from a Maven configuration perspective:

- Maven does not load classes from a WAR artifact, as it would load from a JAR artifact.
- Ideally WAR artifacts are not supposed to be used as a dependency, unless you're building a final EAR artifact.

You have the following choices. All of them require a modification to ProjectB as well:

- Although this is the least likely case, if ProjectA is not used for deploying a web application, you could just change its packaging to jar
- You could move all the required classes to a separate module that builds a JAR, and use this dependency in both ProjectA and ProjectB.
- If you do not want to move the classes to another module/project, you can configure the war plugin in ProjectA to generate a jar artifact alongside the war artifact, using `<attachClasses>true</attachClasses>`

```xml
<project>
    ...
    <artifactId>yourWebapp</artifactId>
    <version>yourVersion</version>
    ...
    <build>
      <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
              <attachClasses>true</attachClasses>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </build>
    ...
</project>
```

This produces a classes artifact in ProjectA, which can be used in ProjectB as a dependency with `<classifier>classes</classifier>`

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>yourGroupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>yourWebapp</artifactId>
    <version>yourVersion</version>
    <classifier>classes</classifier>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll take a shot at these over the weekend and come back!

Comment: I just tried this with no luck. I also tried just to test if changing Project A's configuration with <packaging>jar</packaging> , but that didn't work either